# Flutter listview headers

Tags: listview, flutter

I want to make a listview with headers per day, like the google calendar and the google contacts. I couldn't find an example how to make something like this in a flutter view.
So I want to have a header stick on the left side such as the date for the first item with that date till the next day gets on top and then the previous day has to continue to scroll. Should I work with a MultiChildLayoutDelegate like the animation example in the gallery or can I do this with the listview in some way?

Edit: Made a package myself: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/side_header_list_view

[image: Google contacts]
[image: Google calendar]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For everybody looking for a solution, I just made a library that does this:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/side_header_list_view

You can look for the code on github:
https://github.com/renefloor/side_header_list_view

Basically I show/hide the header part of a listitem depending on the position and added a fixed header on the top left. For now the listitems have to have a fixed height.